# how to comma separate the taxonomy terms so it could be included dynamically in the tax query

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have managed to return the taxonomies that have been selected for a post however, these are returned as one appended list eg `covid1covid2covid3`. I want to be able to separate these out `covid1, covid2, covid3` (not returning the last comma) so that I can use it in my tax query which would return related post dynamically based on these taxonomies. See my code below

```
  $currentID = get_the_ID();
  $post_terms = get_the_terms($currentID, 'vocabulary_1');

  foreach ($post_terms as $post_term) {
      $postTerm = $post_term->slug;  
  }

  $args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'cme-education',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'=>'rand',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'vocabulary_1',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array($postTerm),
            'operator' => 'IN',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in `$postTerm`. First make it array:

```
$postTerm = [];
```

then store terms in it, like this:

```
foreach ($post_terms as $post_term) {
    $postTerm[] = $post_term->slug;
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
$currentID  = get_the_ID();
$post_terms = get_the_terms($currentID, 'vocabulary_1');
$postTerm   = [];
foreach ($post_terms as $post_term) {
    $postTerm[] = $post_term->slug; 
}
$args1 = array(
    'post_type'         => 'cme-education',
    'posts_per_page'    => '1',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           =>'rand',
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'vocabulary_1',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $postTerm,
            'operator'  => 'IN',
            'order'     => 'ASC'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: wow thanks you so much Alex, this work like a charm. When the term are added to the `$postTerm` array, it is not wrapped in `' '`. Does the `terms` array not have to wrap this for eg - `'covid1, covid2, covid3'`?

Comment: Glad to help! And about your question: No, in array each element should be different if we wrap in `' '` this will be one element and it probably string. You can learn more about arrays here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-arrays-in-php--cms-31738

Comment: sorry one more question, how can i get the acf field that relates to a random post that is show. Right now it only shows the acf field for the current activity. so for example I have random posts that have a filed of `opinions` but they all keep showing `conversation`